# Windows Sandbox Security "Access Denied"

Tags: security, permissions, windows-sandbox

I have an issue with Windows permissions and would greatly appreciate a workaround. When I create a Windows Sandbox, I can set a **MappedFolder** to be read/write as follows:

```
<MappedFolder>
    <HostFolder>D:\MySandbox</HostFolder>
    <ReadOnly>false</ReadOnly>
```

This is (sort of) fine, in that I can indeed create files and folders in there and subfolders of that location (note: I'm not testing dodgy software so I have no concerns about specific security - a lot of people seem to believe that Sandbox is "just for testing dodgy software" but it is vastly more useful and powerful than that).

However, we then have two cases with files/folders when I access that mapped folder location:

1. If they are created by the Sandbox, then I *can* delete/modify them from within the Windows Sandbox, but
2. If they were created outside of the Sandbox by the Host system, then I *cannot* delete/modify them from within the Sandbox, getting the error:
   **Access Denied: You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from CFB4B60C-9400-4\WDAGUtilityAccount to make changes to this folder.**

I have tried going to the folder on the Host system and adding "Everyone" in security for that folder, and then giving `Everyone` Full Control rights, but sadly, this does not change anything and I still get the above "Access Denied" error. I have made user that the folder was empty before I started, and made it as open as possible in terms of permissions and inheritance (as far as I am able from what is available under the folder properties Security tab, giving every user Full Control and adding the "Everyone" object etc).

So, this does look to simply be a case of applying the right permissions somehow such that the Sandbox user can delete/modify the files in that folder - we basically need to tell that folder to let **any user** delete/modify objects there; how can I do that? I'd greatly appreciate knowing how to unlock these permissions as it would ease my work inside the Sandbox quite a bit.

Comment: Try to temporarily disable runtime protection in Defender.

Comment: This is most likely a side-effect of how the mapped folder mechanism works. It's possible there is no solution this way. You might not want to hear it, but technical limitations do exist. // Maybe a regular file share could work? I never tried.

Comment: Both of the things you describe are likely intentional.  However, can you confirm how your permissions on the folder are inherited? You should consider **removing** your meta commentary.  If you receive unhelpful commentary, that indicates, "Sandbox is a very constrained container and you can't do anything with it" just flag it so it can be removed.

Comment: It may well be a limitation, and that's fine if so, but 100% of the things that I have been told are impossible on Sandbox, I have either found a fix myself or someone gave me an answer on here or StackOverflow. A regular file share does work, and I've done that before, but it's an extra unnecessary step if the mapped folder is right there. The `WDAGUtilityAccount` is a bit of a mystery but hopefully someone can unravel it. 

Comment: I will remove the meta-commentary (and I planned to remove it, that's why I put it in separate paragraphs so that I could remove later). It was just to stave off the person who poisons the well on every question about Windows Sandbox. I will also delete this comment after you have read it.

Comment: Before generating my Sandbox inside a folder, I first checked that as many permissions as possible were open, and made sure that "Disable Inheritance" was unchecked under Advanced Security Settings. I then tried checking "Replace all child object permissions" and let it run (this should have no effect since permissions are inherited, and indeed, it made no difference). The effective access tab is no help I guess as the `WDAGUtilityAccount` inside the Sandbox does not reside on the Host as such.

Comment: Well I tried it and I could not reproduce the behavior you describe. Is your mapped folder on the host in a special location or does it have an unusual ACL? I created mine in `C:\tmp\mapped-folder`, having created both folders manually. What is the owner of the files as visible from the host?

Comment: My system is a very generic Windows 10 Pro with nothing special or unusual, but wanted to test what you are seeing. I created a folder under my users `%temp%` folder called `MySandbox`. I added `Users`, `Everyone`, `WDAGUtilityAccount` and gave them all Full Control. Only then did I copy in my `.wsb` and `.ps1` startup script that the `.wsb` calls. I start the Sandbox. I then go back to the Host and created "New folder" in there. I go back into the Sandbox and go to `.\Desktop\MySandbox` and try to delete `New folder`. I cannot and the operation fails with the error as in the OP.

Comment: The Owner (and creator) of the files as visible from the host is the user that use on the system (`Boss` just my generic normal user with admin rights that I use on this system). From within the Sandbox, the Owner is listed as `Account Unknown(S-1-5-21-3133562509-3764578197-1861757835-1001)`

Comment: Try moving the `.wsb` file elsewhere. This could be a deliberate security measure. // I see the files as owned by _WDAGUtilityAccount_ inside the sandbox.

Comment: That's interesting ... Are you on Windows 11 by any chance? I'm on Windows 10, it could be that Microsoft tweaked the `WDAGUtilityAccount` in some way on Windows 11. I've tried moving the `.wsb` to various other locations with no luck sadly. Did you create the file on the Host (this is the thing, creation from within the Sandbox is ok, I can delete those files, it's specifically items created on the Host that fail - I'm guessing you are aware of that, but just to double-check).

Comment: I’m not. It’s Windows 10 Enterprise. I tried both ways and everything works.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I'm going to do a complete Reset on this system and another system (both Win 10 Pro) to take them back to a vanilla state and see what happens. Hoping very much that it is some configuration on here (though I cannot think of what, I keep my systems very lean / very little configuration). This issue has been bothering me for months, so I'll do the Reset's and report back. 

Comment: Did a complete reinstall on two different PC's. Formatted all disks on both, installed clean from Windows 10 Pro USB stick. Made no changes. Created an almost empty .wsb that only creates the mapped folder. If I open that, then minimise the Sandbox, so that I am in the Host, and create a folder in the mapped location, then go back into the Sandbox, I cannot delete the folder created there, as described in the OP. This is as clean as it's possible to get for Windows 10, absolutely nothing changed, still getting this sadly.